# Are developers liable for security?

Tags: php, security, web, authentication

If I write a login system for a client who later gets hacked can I or my company be held accountable for whatever damages they claim?

Excuse me if this has been asked already. I did a search and found no relavant answers.

Comment: ... Could you give me the name of your company? I just want to make sure I never, ever have anything to do with you.

Comment: Why @MarioP ? Are your scripts 100% secure? Get over yourself.

Comment: I highly doubt it. But you have to admit, from a customer POV you are presenting yourself in the worst way possible. "Yeah, you could be hacked anytime, there is nothing you can do about it, but just get over it. Not our problem."

Comment: If you haven't performed best endeavours or used best-practises, then you're certainly leaving the door open for action

Comment: @MarioP I wouldn't put it in those words... Dunno what made you think I would...  but I think clients should be aware of the dangers and not necessarily blame their developer if someone is out to get them and succeeds. There should be insurance for these things. Does the developer buy it or the client? As a small business owner I cannot afford to be liable for every client if (worse case scenario) something goes wrong.

Comment: @Mark Baker My understanding is even after best endeavors and best practices no script is 100% secure. Throw in social engineering threats and clients can blame their developers for all kinds of breaches.

Comment: I'm not saying any system can be made 100% secure; but if a developer stores passwords in a plaintext file that is publically accessible if you know what it's called (and I have seen that) then they haven't made any effort to secure the site, and should be liable... while best endeavours doesn't guarantee a site is secure, it does at least give some defence if a customer tries to sue

Comment: The wording of the question made me think so. I agree that the developer isn't responsible for everything that can happen (weak password, just asking the user for his password...), but as a customer of dozens of services, software and otherwise, I also don't see why I should be held responsible for something I couldn't prevent in any way.

Comment: @MarioP precisely why I asked the question. Seems both parties are left holding the bag if an experienced hacker sets his/her sites on your site. But who pays the price? As Richard Chambers said, every case is different. I am still curious what the industry standard practice on the subject in web development is.

Comment: @Chris - this is why software companies, and software contractors, should get themselves professional indemnity cover that fits the jurisdiction you're in.

Comment: Isn't it great how you asked a question and got totally shit on? Maybe folks ought to head over to http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice (both on s.o and IRL...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you consult an attorney for this kind of a legal question.  This is a technical forum and not a place for legal advice.

The software warranty and the courts is a murky area.  It really would depend on what warranties you provide.  Typically with software there is an explicit denial of any warranty and that the software is a best effort however in the US anyone can sue anyone else for almost anything. Just trying to defend a suit can be financially devastating which is why housing contractors have a tendency to have multiple incorporated companies which carry the liability for homes built and insulate the contractors personal assets from any suits.

You do not say what your industry is.  Different industries will have different standards.  For instance in point of sale there are the PCI standards from VISA, etc. on security standards for card account information.

Depending on the industry and the kind of security breach, yes you could be liable.

You really should get the services of a security specialist and a lawyer in your software target industry to discuss this and other legal questions.

The main point to remember is that when there is a breach especially one with financial repercussions, more than likely your customers will look for someone to blame. So you really want to have something in writing that indicates who is responsible for any liability due to a breach. And as part of that there probably should be some description of what would be considered minimal acceptable security practices on the part of the people using the software.

That said a minimal set of necessary practices that you should follow would be something along the lines of the following. I make no claim these are anywhere complete as I am not well versed in computer security.

Reduce privileges and what can be done as much as possible. This hopefully will reduce the amount of damage that may arise when someone breaches the system.

Always assume that input may be tainted so watch out for standard intrusion practices such as SQL Injection or URL modification in the case of REST or other unexpected modifications to input data.

Never assume that just because something is hidden that it will not be found and exploited.

Log everything possible so that when a breach happens, the forensic team will have the data they will need for an investigation.

Passwords are a fairly poor authentication mechanism so you want to beef them up as much as possible. So password aging is important to force passwords to be changed. Password difficulty checks should be used so as to encourage more complicated passwords that will vary from change to change. Passwords should never be maintained in clear text nor should passwords be transmitted in clear text. Encryption is your friend and helpmate.

Biometric information can make for a better authentication mechanism however some people may have features that do not work well with some types of biometric systems such as people whose fingerprints do not work well. Some type of unique device may also be used such as an authentication code generator that is synchronized to a central device or perhaps a central device which sends an authentication code via a text message to your phone when you attempt to log in.

Using the system probably should require a password to be re-entered at the time of some sensitive action especially with systems which may be accessed from a public terminal.

Make sure that it is easy for someone to log out so that they will be more likely to do so as part of closing out a session.

Make it easy for users to be disabled by a supervisor and provide a way to make it easy for a supervisor to generate a report of who has access to what, when have they used their access, and what did they do when they had access.

Borrow a page from Gmail and other e-mail systems to notify the user whose account it is as well as a manager or supervisor via e-mail any access that seems unusual or of a sensitive nature. Also notify via e-mail if any user account type changes are made such as password change along with logging this type of activity.

Comment: Seemed like a question all programmers should think about at some point. I agree with your advice and will consult but I was looking for preliminary information from experienced individuals in the field. I assume whatever's agreed upon in the contract is how liability plays out but I am wondering what is the default course if nothing is stipulated.

Comment: place of jurisdiction MIGHT play a big role, too.

Comment: Most probably true. I was just hoping people would share experiences. Sigh. Design is so much simpler :p